# Сервер и 2 клиента запущены на локальной машине. Путаница в адресах

Tags: golang, клиент-сервер, client

Я на Go пишу в целях саморазвитие чат, и там общение происходит между двумя клиентами через сервер. Т.е. сервер будет сам понимать - от какого клиентам какому транслировать сообщения.

Собственной мой вопрос  вот в чем - т.к. у меня все запущено на локальной машине, т.е. у сервера, и двух клиентов будет один IP-вдрес (127.0.0.1) ?
И не будет ли путаница, если таких клиентов будет множество, и все запущеный на локальной машине?

Может эта проблема мной надумала, если так, то извините, прошу указать правильный упуть.

Спасибо

Comment: Все нормально будет, у них порты будут разные.

Comment: @trollingchar спасибо за ответ. Мой сервер запущен на 60000 порту (на линухе пишу), и оба клиента подключаются на 127.0.0.1 на 60000
Я честно не понял, какие порты будут рзными?(

Comment: Так и должно быть. Сервер держит открытым определенный порт, клиенты на него подключаются, и сервер отвечает им на *их* порты. Можно даже выводить при подключении клиента его IP и порт.